React - sort table api data on click by ascending and descending
In my React web application, I'm trying to implement a feature where when someone first clicks on a  header in a specific column, that column's API data sorts by ascending. On second click, it sorts by descending.
With the logic below, when I click on any  headers, nothing happens - no sorting and no console errors. Each  in the code below's handleHeaderClick function takes in the value coming from the API.
Here's the snippet of code where I'm trying to implement the logic, which lives inside of my "Table.tsx" component:
export const MainTable = ({ data, isLoading, error }: MainTableProps) => {

 ...

  // Sorting logic
  const rawData = data.map((group) => group.equipments).flat();
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState(rawData);
  const [order, setOrder] = useState("ASC");

  const handleHeaderClick = (col) => {
    if (order === "ASC") {
      const sorted = [...tableData].sort((a, b) =>
        a[col].toLowerCase() > b[col].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
      );
      setTableData(sorted);
      setOrder("DSC");
    }
    if (order === "DSC") {
      const sorted = [...tableData].sort((a, b) =>
        a[col].toLowerCase() < b[col].toLowerCase() ? 1 : -1
      );
      setTableData(sorted);
      setOrder("ASC");
    }
  };

  ...

  return (
    <>
      <TableContainer>
        <Table variant="simple">
          <Thead>
            <Tr>
              <Th onClick={() => handleHeaderClick("manufacturer")}>
                {t("manu")}
              </Th>
              <Th onClick={() => handleHeaderClick("model")}>{t("model")}</Th>
              <Th
                onClick={() => handleHeaderClick("product-family-display-name")}
              >
                {t("desc")}
              </Th>
              <Th onClick={() => handleHeaderClick("serial-number")}>
                {t("serial")}
              </Th>
              <Th onClick={() => handleHeaderClick("state")}>{t("prov")}</Th>
              <Th onClick={() => handleHeaderClick("city")}>{t("city")}</Th>
              <Th
                onClick={() => handleHeaderClick("regular-price")}
                className="align-right"
              >
                {t("regPrice")}
              </Th>
              <Th
                onClick={() => handleHeaderClick("price")}
                className="align-right sale-header"
              >
                {t("salePrice")}
              </Th>
            </Tr>
          </Thead>
          <Tbody>
            {currentPageData.map((equipment: Equipment) => (
              <Tr key={equipment.id}>
                <Td>
                  {equipment.manufacturer.length > 0
                    ? equipment.manufacturer
                    : "N/A"}
                </Td>
                <Td>{equipment.model.length > 1 ? equipment.model : "N/A"}</Td>
                <Td>{equipment["product-family-display-name"]}</Td>
                <Td>{equipment["serial-number"]}</Td>
                <Td>{equipment.state}</Td>
                <Td>
                  <a
                    target="_blank"
                    href={`https://website.com/locations/${
                      equipment.city.indexOf(" ")
                        ? equipment.city.replace(/\s/g, "-")
                        : equipment.city
                    }`}
                  >
                    {equipment.city}
                  </a>
                </Td>
                <Td className="align-right reg-price">
                  {formatPrice(Number(equipment["regular-price"]?.text))}
                </Td>
                <Td className="align-right sale-price">
                  <strong>
                    {formatPrice(Number(equipment["price"]?.text))}
                  </strong>
                </Td>
              </Tr>
            ))}
          </Tbody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </>
  );
};


try console.log(sorted) to know whats is going on your sort fucntion.

@peymankhalili Just tried. On first click of the manufacturer heading, it sorts by all blank ascending manufacturer values. On second click, it sorts by the descending values. The logic works, just a matter of getting the table to sort..

Why using :
{currentPageData.map((equipment: Equipment) => (...
use: {tableData.map(
currentPageData.map() will not updated after setTableData(sorted);

So your comment made the logic work! However I use currentPageData to filter the table as a whole with pagination: const currentPageData = useMemo(     () => filteredData.slice(offset, offset + itemsPerPage),     [filteredData, currentPage]   );. So I need it to work with currentPageData, as other filtering is tied into it.

show me currentPageData's definition??

Live link: https://stackblitz.com/~/github.com/cloudmako09/sets-desktop, inside Table.tsx
